# Unable to populate spinner with array list?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner

I am getting the values from shared preferences and adding the key values to an array list. I have 3 key values saved in the shared preferences but only one of those values is getting added to the spinner. I want all the values in the list to be added to the spinner. Please help I'm new here, I did go through other similar questions, but I couldn't find a solution.

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String, ?> allEntries = mPrefs.getAll(); 
    allEntries.values().remove(false); // removing values that are "false"
```

˚

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {

    languages = new ArrayList();

        languages.add(entry.getKey());



    }


    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because You are creating new instance from `ArrayList` everytime

you should move it outside for loop like this.

```
languages = new ArrayList();

for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
    languages.add(entry.getKey());
}
```